# re-polarised approaches to treatment and rehabilitation

Tags: phrase-meaning

The BMJ tweeted:

> Many patients with “long” covid are experiencing extreme fatigue, a situation that has re-polarised approaches to treatment and rehabilitation. @Melanie_Newman reports

[Source](https://twitter.com/bmj_latest/status/1408803512327225345)

I understand "re-polarised approaches to treatment and rehabilitation" as "made approaches have two ends: one end is treatment and the other is rehabilitation."  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Not so much two 'ends' as two differing attitudes to the treatment of  fatigue, I think. Oxford's Definition 3 of **polarise**: _Divide or cause to divide into two sharply contrasting groups or sets of opinions or beliefs. - 
"the cultural sphere has polarized into two competing ideological positions"_

Comment: "into" is much clearer than "to", which is ambiguous to me.

Comment: If you mean 'approaches to treatment and rehab.', it means that there are two different approaches, not that the two things are separate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kate said, when discussing issues of opinion (and especially politics) **polarise** means **separate into two (or more) parts** (as in magnetic poles). In this case it is not that "treatment" and "rehabilitation" are separated; rather there are differing approaches to "treatment and rehabilitation" (as a group), and those different approaches are what are being more and more separate.